# WPFToolkit / AvalonDock / Event

Tags: wpf, controls, wpftoolkit, avalondock

**What I like to have:**
A Dashboard which the user can realigned/move/resize a board with Drag&Drop ability.
The easiest solution could be perhabs to use simple dock windows like AvalonDock. But because I don't like floating windows, I must be possible to automatic re-dock the floating window if the user don't dock it.

**What I tried:**
I found in `LayoutContent.Dock` the method, which I need to call when the user stops dragging the floating window. I think, after  `LayoutFloatingWindowControl.FilterMessage` -> `case Win32Helper.WM_EXITSIZEMOVE:` would be the best place. But after this point I found no event to notify me. Do I didn't see the solution? Next problem: How can I get the object of type `LayoutContent` to call `Dock`? :/

Can I continue to pursue my idea?
Or did you know other free controls or ideas to realize this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AvalonDock LayoutDocument and LayoutAnchorable (the controls that hold the content) have a property `CanFloat`set it to false and it will not be able to float and you don't need to dock it.

see the docs: https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/AvalonDock

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But if this flag is false, then I can't move any window (board) at all. I need more a property like "AutoDock". If the user move a window, but don't dock it to another side of a other board, then the moved board docks automatically to his old position again.

Comment: what is your problem with the `Dock` method

Comment: What do you mean? I don't have a problem with `Dock`

Comment: Why can't you call the `Dock` function?

Comment: I believe his whole point is WHEN / WHERE to react to add a hooke to be notified of the move to be able to call Dock.  You'd have to handle the order and side it appeared too... but that's another problem.